# Why isn't there a "memsize" in C which returns the size of a memory block allocated in the heap using malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management

ok. It can be called anything else as in [_msize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc(v=vs.80).aspx) in Visual Studio.

But why is it not in the standard to return the size of the memory given the memory block alloced using malloc? Since we can not tell how much memory is pointed to by the return pointer following malloc, we could use this "memsize" call to return that information should we need it. "memsize" would be implementation specific as are malloc/free

Just asking as I had to write a [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852072/simple-c-implementation-to-track-memory-malloc-free) sometime back to store some additional bytes for the size.

Comment: Since you, the programmer, were originally responsible for allocating the memory, you should already know what size the block is.

Comment: @Maxim Yegorushkin only case I had to write the wrappers was using third party library which need some memory allocation/deallocation as well keep a global count of how much memory was allocated. So when freeing, I needed to know how much memory was allocated for the block about to be freed. This was required for the library to work.

Comment: @Paul R That is correct hence the wrapper I mention. I am just curious hence the question

Comment: @MeThinks: But `free()` manages this for you already!

Comment: @MeThinks:  Um, huh?  Shouldn't the third-party library have its own memory management functions in that case?  And should the Standards be modified for every oddly written library around?

Comment: @ Paul R Yes but only when freeing. The use case I mention above requires be to subtract the amount I am about to free from some global variable so I keep count of the earlier allocated size. I am probably asking too much but at the time I thought why isn't there such a function.

Comment: @David Thornley No the standard shouldn't. But this information is already available to the memory allocation routines as free would need it anyay

Comment: @David Thornley Shouldn't the third-party library have its own memory management functions in that case? Not in this case as it was being ported to our platform so it couldn't know how to allocate. Therefore we had to provide memory allocation/free/reallocation routines. It was embedded platform just to mention.

Comment: Note, there are several `malloc()` replacements that offer that kind of information and additional debugging features. The standard is the bare minimum needed to build library code that does what you want.

Comment: @MeThinks I've been writing C code for 30+ years, including C library development, implemented a couple of malloc libraries ... and I can tell you that most of the answers and comments here are pretty danged bad. It would be a useful function, it isn't redundant, it doesn't indicate poor design, it doesn't put any burden on the malloc implementation. The basic answer is that the original Unix developers at Bell Labs didn't think to provide it, and adding it later would have been incompatible with any existing malloc implementation.

Comment: @Jim: what? The standard has been issued twice, C89 and C99, and both times added functions which weren't previously available in all implementations. So if it truly is just an historical accident, why wasn't `memsize` one of the functions added? In fact the standards authors both times must have consciously decided to omit it, presumably for a reason better than, "implementers will have to add three lines of code". The incompatibility argument was not successfully made when VLAs were added.

Comment: @Steve I served on the C Standards committee, X3J11. Stuff generally got added only if the people who wanted it had enough clout -- mostly compiler vendors.

Comment: @Jim: so the current situation is that pretty much all OS vendors provide it, but none of them want it to be standardized?

Comment: The comment above, which I don't think I've seen before, obviously twisted my words. Vendors didn't clamor to have memsize added; that's nothing like opposing it being added. And the claims that "the standards authors both times must have consciously decided to omit it" and " pretty much all OS vendors provide it" are baseless. Also " presumably for a reason better than ..." -- the default for standards committees is to not add things. Many worthwhile things were rejected by X3J11 for no "better reason".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the C library, including `malloc`, was designed for minimum overhead. A function like the one you want would require the implementation to record the exact size of the allocation, while implementations may now choose to "round" the size up as they please, to prevent actually reallocating in `realloc`.

Storing the size requires an extra `size_t` per allocation, which may be heavy for embedded systems. (And for the PDP-11s and 286s that were still abundant when C89 was written.)

Comment: True. Of course, the standard could simply say that the return value of _msize in only guaranteed to be at least as large as the allocated memory block...

Comment: I like the sound of this answer. Let us see what the others say. Doesn't free need the size anyway otherwise how does the implementation know how much to free? I am aware this is implementation dependent but whatever implementation would need to "remember" the size :)

Comment: This makes no sense.  The size is already recorded (otherwise `free()` wouldn't work).  I think the real answer is that nobody really saw any use for it.  The OP's situation is fairly unique and more indicative of a poor library design than a deficiency in the C library.

Comment: More usefully, the standard could have defined that this hypothetical "memsize" is permitted to return larger than what was requested, but if it does so then the extra memory is addressable by the program. This covers the common case (rounding up to a size that's convenient for the implementation details of the allocator) in a way that's potentially useful. Some programs can benefit from the extra memory, for instance if it's an I/O buffer, a circular message queue, a sub-allocator, or an expanding array (like `std::vector` in C++).

Comment: @Steve Jessop: IMHO, `std::vector` would benefit more from a `reallocate` member in C++ allocators.

Comment: @larsmans: sure, but that's also harder because an adequate C++ `reallocate` must copy correctly according to type. Note that `vector` doesn't allocate arrays of initialized objects as with `new[]`, it uses the Allocator interface to get raw data and initializes it itself, so such a `reallocate` would also have to copy only the objects that the caller tells it are initialized. Pushes a lot of fiddly details down the call stack. `realloc` only handles POD, so doesn't need any of that. What `std::vector` would most benefit from is reallocate with move semantics, I suppose, what does C++0x do?

Comment: TMN and Steve Jessop are correct. This is a poor answer, as there's no need -- or desire -- to record the exact size requested via malloc; memsize should return the actual amount available, and that is necessarily known; if it weren't the memory could not be reallocated after being freed.

Comment: @JimBalter: Some systems might allocate heap storage from the top down using a scheme which stores the length of each block at the end and uses a bit just before the start of each block (possibly shared with the length field of the previous block) to indicate whether a block has been freed.  Under such a system, finding the length of an allocation would require a heap walk, but freeing a block would not require that its length be known until the system found the end of the block (and thus its length) while processing a malloc request.

Comment: @JimBalter: I don't know how many systems do or did such a thing, but a requirement that an implementation provide an allocation-length function would require that any such implementation change in a way that might break existing code.  That having been said, the Standard could (and IMHO should) have offered a function which would either report the size of an allocation *or report that it was unavailable* as well as a function that would *attempt* to resize an allocation *without invalidating any pointers to it* and indicate whether it was able to do so.

Comment: @JimBalter: All implementations would be able to conform to the indicated requirements by reporting that the size was unavailable, or that a resize attempt failed, but some patterns could be made much more efficient in cases where such functions succeed.

Comment: @supercat No implementation works that way because it's dumb; it has no benefits over storing the size at the top and several drawbacks. And reporting that the size isn't available is useless -- the use cases avoid redundantly storing size information, a design decision. In the absence of a standardized `memsize`, they must store it. Anyway, I don't want to be drawn into a discussion with you so this is my last comment here.

Answer (score 2):

To turn this around, why should there be?  There's plenty of stuff in the Standards already, particularly the C++ standard.  What are your use cases?

You ask for an adequately-sized chunk of memory, and you get it (or a null pointer or exception).  There may or may not be additional bytes allocated, and some of these may be reserved.  This is conceptually simple:  you ask for what you want, and you get something you can use.

Why complicate it?

Comment: Wasn't trying to complicate. Just curious as I had a use case where I needed it. And I have a seen a good number of questions on Stackoverflow on this very need to know the size. This in no way plays down your very valid critique

Comment: @MeThinks:  Sure, just trying to point out that adding features to Standards isn't free.  FWIW, I don't remember seeing noticeable numbers of questions on this.

Comment: Use cases for a slight variant include an I/O buffer, a circular message queue, a sub-allocator, or an expanding array (like std::vector in C++). All of those can efficiently use any extra memory that the allocator wastes, if only they know how much there is. That aside: Windows, linux and OSX all have proprietary extensions to do this, suggesting that there *are* good reasons to complicate it. I wonder, are there any C implementations/allocators which couldn't easily support it? If so then that's a reason not to complicate it, which probably trumps the good reasons for adding it.

Comment: As for noticeable numbers of questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208644/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-memory-block-allocated-using-malloc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232691/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197839/is-there-any-way-to-determine-the-size-of-a-c-array-programmatically-and-if-n

Comment: @Steve Somewhere along the line, free must know how big the memory chunk is, else one could never allocate from it again. I have written several mallocs and have read the innards of numerous others and I can assure you that there are no implementations that couldn't easily support it. But it's way too late to add it to the standard because that would make any code that uses it incompatible with all existing implementations.

Comment: @Jim: free knows how big the chunk *allocated* was, it doesn't need to know how big the chunk *requested* was, and it's not always clear which is being asked for by the various people who say, "how can I find out how big my array is?". If you've reviewed all implementations of malloc then brilliant, get yourself to the C1x committee and report, because they *can* add new functions. There is no need for code that consciously uses C1x features to work on C99 implementations, and anyway those implementations can always add C1x features as extensions (as with C++0x).

Comment: @Steve no one cares how big a chunk was requested, only what's available. Even if someone did care about the former, it's the latter that can be provided for free, and there's no reason not to provide some functionality just because some *other* functionality would be expensive for some implementations. "If you've reviewed all implementations of malloc" I didn't say that and you know it. But the fact is that I was on the X3J11 committee and I know how it works (I happen to be the first person on the planet to vote to approve the C standard -- alphabetical order, he he.)

Comment: @Jim: OK, I was exaggerating a bit, but it was intended as a plausible point. Maybe the C standard committee does things differently from C++, which does take straw polls of members present in order to determine whether a potential feature is (a) compatible with, and (b) difficult to provide in, existing implementations. Providing the easy form of `memsize` doesn't seem to me to be any different from many other incompatible changes made in new versions of the standard. Your other explanation ("nobody asked for it") seems much more likely than, "it can't be added because it's a new function".

Comment: @Steve When I was on X3J11 it was quite conservative; things were only added if a strong needs case could be made, usually by the compiler vendors, who dominated the committee and didn't want any additional work; even things as easy to provide as memsize were routinely shot down.

Comment: @Jim What were some examples? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any definite answer. The developers of the standard probably considered it, and weighed the pros and cons. Anything that goes into a standard must be implemented by *every* implementation, so adding things to it places a significant burden on developers. I guess they just didn't find that feature useful enough to warrant this.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the wrapper that you talk about *is* provided by the standard.  If you allocate a block of memory with **std::vector**, you can use the member function **vector::size()** to determine the size of the array and use **vector::capacity()** to determine the size of the allocation (which might be different).

C, on the other hand, is a low-level language which leaves such concerns to be managed by the developer, since tracking it dynamically (as you suggest) is not strictly necessary and would be redundant in many cases.

Comment: I included a C++ answer since the question originally included C++ and used a C++ tag.  Also, the C++ answer provides context for my answer to the OP's actual question: "Why isn't there a memsize() for use with malloc() in C/C++".