# Sizeof operator Implementation : How it computes size at compile time?

Tags: c, sizeof

Sizeof operator is compile time operator. converts sizeof expression with constant result values during compile time. [Exception variadic templates c99]

Normally compiler fixes size for variables at compile time. **for array n**.
But when i print sizeof array it gives correct size?
is this code allots memory at compile time for n?

**How sizeof is evaluated then?**

how about the array a[] in function?

```
int fun(int n)
{
    char a[n+3];
    return sizeof(a);
}
int
main( )
{
    int i;
    while(i!=-1){
        scanf("%d",&i);
        int n[i];
        printf("\nsize: %d %d\n",fun(3),sizeof n);
    }
}
```

when i try this :
sizeof prints size of n correctly [(sizeof (int)) * i] but the function gives wrong results always 6?

How sizeof is implemented and calculates size (for float,int,...datatypes , variables, array, ...) ?

Any code is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How sizeof(array) works at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078283/how-sizeofarray-works-at-runtime)

Comment: "the function gives wrong results always 6?" -- How is that the wrong result? `sizeof(char)*(3+3)` == 6

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you mention, `sizeof` calculations are normally made at compile time, by the compiler.  That's not always true (for example, C99/C11 variable length arrays), but it's a reasonable approximation.

Since the compiler knows (or decides) the size of every type, it can just make a simple constant substitution during compilation.

For your examples, `a` and `n` are both variable length arrays, and the `sizeof` operator is applied at runtime.

From C11, **Section 6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators**, paragraph 2:

> The **`sizeof`** operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

Editorial note:  `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`, so you should use a `%zu` format specifier instead of `%d`.  Your compiler may warn you if you turn on the appropriate flags.

Comment: + you are champion today for `sizeof` operators :)

Comment: [if sizeof can't be applied to functions; is there any way to ensure it] (i'm using codeblocks:mingw how to make code strictly c99)

Comment: Why do you want to apply `sizeof` to a function?

Comment: What's stopping you from getting a C spec and reading about it?  "The `_Alignof` operator yields the alignment requirement of its operand type."

Comment: Online link to c spec? [i searched but book explains basic  but concepts, not standards].

Comment: C11 spec draft: [PDF link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia explains the implementation of `sizeof` pretty well, See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) for detail.

> It is the responsibility of compilers to implement the sizeof operator correctly for each target platform. In many cases, there will be an official Application Binary Interface (ABI) document for the platform, specifying formats, padding, and alignment for the data types, to which the compiler must conform. In most cases, sizeof is a compile-time operator, which means that during compilation sizeof expressions get replaced by constant result-values. However, sizeof applied to a variable length array, introduced in C99, requires computation during program execution.`

Answer (score 0):

When the operand of `sizeof` is not a variable-length array (VLA), then it `sizeof` not really "calculate" anything. The result is immediately known to the compiler as a compile-time constant. That constant is substituted in place of `sizeof` during compilation.

If the operand is VLA, then the compiler simply generates code that retrieves the size information from the VLA itself. So, yes, in general case  a typical implementation does store the size of the VLA inside the VLA itself. In your example that means that the memory allotted for `a` will also include a location to store the `n + 3` value.

The compiler can, of course, optimize this evaluation in obvious cases and even replace it with compile-time constant in the most obvious cases. In your example the compiler might be smart enough not to retrieve the size from the array `a`, but instead immediately realize that the size is equal to `n + 3`.