# Realloc simply not diong anything, not erroring

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I've got the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    //just checking to see where the stack 
    printf("The stack is around %p\n", &argc); is, making sure arr isn't in it
    char ** arr = malloc(8*sizeof(char*));
    printf("arr is size %li, at %p\n", sizeof(arr), arr);
    arr = realloc(arr, 100); //I picked a weird number to show it isn't doing anything. I've picked different numbers (like 200, 2*sizeof(char*)*sizeof(arr), and 16)
    printf("arr is size %li, at %p\n", sizeof(arr), arr);
}
```

That's the entirety of the file (it's a unit test; I was noticing it elsewhere)

The output of the above is as follows:

```
The stack is around 0x7fff5b94d12c
arr is size 8, at 0x120f010
arr is size 8, at 0x120f010
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what realloc should do. I'm **expecting** the following output.

```
The stack is around 0x7fff5b94d12c
arr is size 8, at 0x120f010
arr is size <size>, at <somewhere>
```

where `<size>` is... something odd like 12... at least not 8 and `<somewhere>` is most likely `0x120f010` but possibly anywhere reasonable.

Are my expectations wrong or am I using realloc incorrectly?

Comment: The real problem is that you are misunderstanding `sizeof`...

Comment: You're right, I am. Thank you... now to debug the original program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your program is correct, because

- Neither `malloc` nor `realloc` have anything to do with the automatic storage (i.e. "the stack"). They allocate memory from the dynamic storage area (i.e. "the heap"). One should not expect the position of the top of the stack to change in response to calls to `malloc`, `realloc`, or for that matter, any other function.
- The value of `sizeof(arr)` does not depend on what you have allocated to it. It is computed at compile time, and it is always equal to the size of a pointer. On your system, pointers use 8 bytes.
- `malloc` often gives you more memory that you ask, and stores the actual value in a special location that `realloc` can access at a later time. If you `realloc` down, or `realloc` within the bounds, the value returned by `realloc` does not change. That's the reason why it may perform better than simply calling `malloc` and `memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (which I obviously found most accurate, though Ed's was great as well). Regarding the stack vs. heap, I was just trying to make sure that I wasn't mallocing incorrectly and writing over parts of it with the stack. In the original program, I'd been getting issues that looked like certain strings were being overwritten (they were; I was reallocating a space much smaller than necessary), so that's why that line there.

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof arr
```

That's the same as

```
sizeof char**
```

The size of a pointer isn't going to change, and taking the size of a pointer is not going to tell you how much memory it refers to.  Pointers are not arrays, and `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time.

As for the address bit, `realloc` doesn't guarantee that the memory block was moved.  It could simply expand it successfully and return the same address.

Also, I realize this is just example code, but be aware that, if `realloc` failed, you leaked what `arr` originally pointed to.

Comment: Pedantic: In C99, `sizeof` can be a runtime operation (if used on a variable-length array). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10078283/575615

Comment: @Medo42: Ah, yes, good call.  I've been writing C in C89 land for some time now, didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon, and in fact a bit expected, that a `malloc` call followed directly by `realloc` would not change the address of the pointer.  In many cases the allocator can just extend the amount of memory reserved at the address and not have to move the pointer.  This is what is happening here.

This isn't something you should ever depend on though.  It's just a quirk of the implementation

Comment: This isn't really at all what this question is focusing on.

Answer (score 0):

If your assumption is that `realloc()` has to return a different pointer, then your assumption is wrong.

Typically if you're reducing the size of the allocated memory or leaving it "as is", then `realloc()` can return the same pointer and avoid copying data, etc.

Sometimes if you're increasing the size of the allocated memory `realloc()` can check if there's free space above the existing space and still return the same pointer (and avoid copying data).

Mostly, it's only when there is no free space above the allocated memory that `realloc()` must copy the data somewhere else and return a different pointer.