# Link of compressed pages in zsmalloc

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to understand zsmalloc allocator used in zram and zswap but I am stuck in code of init_zspage in zsmalloc.c

```
    link = (struct link_free *)kmap_atomic(page) +
                    off / sizeof(*link);
```

Here link is not initialized. The problem is what will be the value of sizeof(*link) if it not initializes. As far I know sizeof(*link) must be calculated before assignment.

Comment: look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731500/using-sizeof-with-a-dynamically-allocated-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This size will be computed at compile time.

```
struct link_free *link;

235 struct link_free {
236         /* Handle of next free chunk (encodes <PFN, obj_idx>) */
237         void *next;
238 };
```

i.e. size of this struct = size of pointer. So this is what are youasking about?